# Cypress's get stops at first occurence

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

When I run my test against that HTML code

```
<body>
  <div tester='notmatching'>
    foo
  </div>
  <div tester='matching'>
    bar
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Cypress doesn't look beyond the first "div".

Here is my test :

```
context('Home', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://example.org')
  })
  it('Find a div', () => {
    cy.get('div').should('have.attr', 'tester', 'matching')
  })
})
```

Si I get the following error :

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected '[ <div>, 1 more... ]' to have attribute 'tester' with the value 'matching', but the value was 'notmatching'
```

So when I put the line :

```
cy.get('div').should('have.attr', 'tester', 'notmatching')
```

It works.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: you sure that both of the divs are on the same level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to target the second matching element using eq:

```
cy.get('div').eq(1).should('have.attr', 'tester', 'matching')
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax

**EDIT:**

If you want to iterate through them and check each one, you could do this:

```
cy
  .get('div')
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    if ($el.attr('tester') === 'matching') {
      // do something here
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you just want to match the div with that attribute - you can do this:

```
cy.get("div[tester='matching']").should(...
```

Comment: Is there a way to loop over all the `div` elements present in the document and find the first one having that attribute ?

Comment: yes! `cy.get('ul>li').each(function () {...}) // Iterate through each 'li'`